# Visual Studio 2015 CE Javascript editor not recognizing '(?' in regex

Tags: javascript, regex, visual-studio-2015, lookbehind

I'm looking for your help because I'm having a weird issue with the Visual Studio 2015 editor. I have a javascript file that contains a regular expression that uses a lookbehind, something like this:

```js
var regexStr = /(?<=[0-9a-zA-Z]+)(\/{2,})(?=[0-9a-zA-Z]+)/;
```

For some reason, the question mark is "breaking" the syntax and the code editor shows it as an error, although the regex is working as expected.

Do you guys know if the '(?' is defined as a special char in the Visual Studio 2015 editor?

Greetings fellow programmers!

Comment: The JS syntax highlighting seems to miss the ECMAScript 2018 regex support

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for your comment, that may be the issue. I'll look deeper into that!

Comment: I don't get an error or warning with your code although the coloring is very odd.  You would think the regex would all be one color.

Comment: @Mark For any reason I get the "Unexpected quantifier" error when I add the question mark, if I remove it the error goes away.

Comment: @MarcoRosales Are you actually looking for help with VS Code or with Visual Studio 2015? Your initial tag and titled said VS 2015, but your initial post says VS Code. They are two different product. I edited your post to change the tag to VS Code and fix some errors where you referred to it as VS 2015 and my edit was approved, but now I see you have edited it back and brought the ambiguity back to the post. You even changed "JavaScript" back to "javaScript". What is the deal? Editing errors and ambiguity back into your post isn't very helpful for people here trying to help you.

Comment: @StephenMIrving You're right. I missed the title of the post, gonna fix it right now. My question refers to VS 2015 CE, will update the thread to remove that ambiguity. Greetings.

Comment: Ok then, thanks you. I'm sorry that I guessed wrong when I made my first edit when I assumed you actually meant VSCode over VS2015 when you intended the opposite. I think you may want to look for an extension to update the VS2015 syntax highlighting for modern JS/ECMAScript standards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing I would say is that Visual Studio 2015 is a sub-optimal tool for JavaScript development. There are *much* better tools for web development that are available for free. This could potentially be seen as opinion based, but developers vote with their feet when it comes to tooling and what makes their workflow easier and faster, and very few people are picking VS 2015 for JS development in 2020. So I have to ask, is there a reason you are locked into using particular piece of software and version for JavaScript? Are you open to using a different tool? If so, comment below and I will add a list of choices for editors and IDE's that are more popular choices and that will most likely make your life as a developer easier.

Assuming though that you want to continue using VS 2015, regardless of its myriad flaws, and just want this particular thing solved, I think that what you are seeing may be the result of updated ECMAScript/JavaScript syntax leaving VS 2015 in the dust. It could also be that this was always just a bug. I first suggest ensuring that you have updated the base application as much as VS 2015 will allow you to. Are you using a pro or community version? Even if you stuck with Visual Studio, you could still get a more recent year's version, and if you are already using the community version that update would be free. Once you are sure you have updated the software as much as possible, I would suggest looking for an extension that could help you with this particular issue.

You can search the [Visual Studio Extension Marketplace](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/) yourself, and I would look for one that offers things like "JavaScript syntax highlighting" or "updated JavaScript grammar".

Here is an extension I just found that may help you as well:

- [Regex Editor](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioProductTeam.RegexEditor) - "IntelliSense, syntax coloring, in-place testing and more for your regular expressions, right inside the editor!"

Comment: Hi Stephen, I have to stick with VS 2015 since it is a work requirement, so there's no much I can do about it. I'm working the the Community Edition of VS2015 and as you've recommended, I'll try to install a newer version of the regex extension and see if that works. Thanks a lot for your help and you time!

Comment: You're welcome Marco, happy to help. Sorry I could not find the exact cause of your issue, but I wish you luck in solving it.